# How to cast a generic class of type to same generic of less derived type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I have a piece of code similar to this

```
interface IModel
{
}

class ModelBase : IModel
{
}

class Model : ModelBase
{
}

class Base<T>
{
    public Base()
    {
        //I need to work with Base<Model> as if it is Base<IModel>
        var modelBase = this as Base<IModel>;
        Console.WriteLine(stringBase?.ToString()??"Null");
    }
}
class Child : Base<Model>
{
}
void Main()
{
    new Child();
}
```

I Want in the base class to make a special processing if it is of type IModel
I can check if T is IModel using

```
(typeof(IModel)).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))
```

but I want to cast the Base class itself.

### The real situation is

I have a ConfigurationBase class that inherits from EntityTypeConfiguration
I wish to make special configuration if the T is IAuditedModel {creationDate, createdBy..} in the same class, but I used another solution is to create another class AuditedConfigurationBase as the following

```
internal class AuditedConfigurationBase<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : class, IAuditedModel
{
    public AuditedConfigurationBase()
    {
        ProcessAuditedConfiguration();
    }

    private void ProcessAuditedConfiguration()
    {
        CongigureCreatedBy();
        ConfigureModifiedBy();
    }

    private void CongigureCreatedBy()
    {
        Property(audited => audited.CreatedBy)
            .HasMaxLength(Constants.MaxLength.Name)
            .IsRequired();
    }

    private void ConfigureModifiedBy()
    {
        Property(audited => audited.ModifiedBy)
            .HasMaxLength(Constants.MaxLength.Name)
            .IsRequired();

    }
}
```

I wished to make that in one BaseConfiguration, this is the situation.
I don't deal with instance of the class T.

Comment: What happens with `this as Base<IModel>`. Does that work?

Comment: no, always return null only work if Base<Model>.

Comment: Basically a `Base<Model>` *isn't* a `Base<IModel>`. They're simply not compatible types...

Comment: @JonSkeet : nice, this is clear, but is there any other solution for this situation.

Comment: Not really, because we don't know anything more about the "situation" other than that you want to do something that isn't possible. We don't know the bigger picture about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I can make new class that inherit form Base where T is IModel and do the business, but I wanted to make it simple for consumer to inherit from one class and don't make him make more decisions.

Comment: @ahmedsafan86 Generics just don't work that way. Take a `List<Model>` for example. You can't just cast that to `List<object>` even tough a `Model` can be cast to `object`.

Comment: thanks I new there is no covariance in classes it is only in interfaces and delegates, but hoped if there were any easy trick instead of making wrappers. but I see there is no trick.

Comment: Do you want to access Properties of the interface IModel?

Comment: @CSharpie : yes I have a method that take a Func<T, bool>, I need to access a specific property of T that exists in IModel.

Comment: @ahmedsafan86 Why do you need to cast the whole class (Model<...>) then? Please provide a complete pseudocode example that shows what you are actually trying to accheive.

Comment: @CSharpie I provided the question with more real code to make it more clear for you.

Comment: @ahmedsafan86 Now you have a class AuditedConfigurationBase<T> with a generic constraint. You were talking about a general baseclass. this gets more and more confusing.